# using jquery to get all html in div

Tags: jquery

im tying to use jquery to get all html in a div "#THIS_DIV" then add it to "#ADD_HTML_HERE"
example:

```
<div id="THIS_DIV">
<!-- I Want To get All This Html-->
      <div class="something">
        <div class="something">




        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- I Want To get All This Html-->    
</div>

<div id="ADD_HTML_HERE"></div>
```

Comment: `$("#ADD_HTML_HERE").html($("#THIS_DIV").html())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jquery [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function returns the contents of an element as well as setting them.

If no parameters are given, it returns the HTML of the given element.

If given HTML it will insert that into the given element.

```
// Obtain the HTML
var html = $('#THIS_DIV').html();

// Set it
$('#ADD_HTML_HERE').html(html);
```

This can be done in one line:

```
$('#ADD_HTML_HERE').html($('#THIS_DIV').html());
```

Comment: Thanks been working on this for a while couldn't figure it out.